# Crash just after UIView creation

Tags: ios, cocoa, memory, crash

I have a crashgroup that I don't understand and which I did not manage to reproduce yet. Does anyone have a clue what is going on here? To me it look like there is a view that is created, and maybe deallocated right away? In fact I also often see reference to the `init` method of some of my views just before this stacktrace, But the views are varying so it seemes that I have this problem in many places of my app. :-(

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: retain

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000182b81bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                           0x0000000183dd68e4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 320
2   QuartzCore                           0x0000000185bf3374 CA::Layer::set_delegate(objc_object*) + 68
3   UIKit                                0x00000001881f6538 -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:] + 576
4   UIKit                                0x00000001881f5ff8 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 684
5   UIKit                                0x00000001881f5ce8 -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 136
```

Is that fact that is says: `objc_msgSend() selector name: retain` some kind of clue? To me it look like `retain` is being called, but why should it crash then?

Comment: It is probably trying to retain something that has already been released.  While trying to reproduce it, turn on zombies in your build scheme.

Comment: Did you every solve this issue? I am having a very similar crash.

Comment: No fishinear, I still have this problem.

Comment: @knutigro what about now, did you solve this issue? :D  Did you try running locally, but without debugger, or a release version.. or from testflight?

Answer (score 1):

This is a memory management issue. You will need to replicate the conditions of the crash with Zombies turned on. Some object has vanished out from under its pointer, and Zombies will tell you what object it is.

The detail article on this kind of crash:

http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Comment: Thanks but replicating this is very hard since it doesn't happen regularly and it never happened to me in the debugger. I just see it in our crashlogs which is collected from thousands of users and hundred thousands of sessions. I still would like to understand what is going on though.